# How to reload main controller in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, controller, reload

I am working in Angular.js (Angular 1) website - http://keraiz.com/.

I make a main controller for all common thing like login, cart. but when I login or add something to cart it does not show until I reload complete page. If I use $state.reload() then, the controller for page is reload but how I reload my main controller.

Comment: How are your using that controller ? can you show some part of your html ?

Comment: why not use global scope instead.

Comment: main controller covers all page .. and page controller like home controller cover pages except header things

Comment: If I use rootscope insteed scope, can this issue resolve ?

Comment: try `$window.location.reload();`

Comment: It is a solution but I do not want to reload whole page for just adding a product.

Comment: i am thinking that scope is not updating.PLease check once whether your scope is updating successfully.If yes then after scope use $scope.apply()

Comment: probably a solution is to use an event to update your scope , try to make a working simple example at plunkr

Answer (score 0):

You should use $rootScope for user and cart since they should be accessible application wide or a service/factory is to be used.
Also you are using $rootScope and $scope for the same variables like

```
$rootScope.cartProducts=response.data.response;
$rootScope.totalItem = $scope.cartProducts.length;
```

totalItem is also in the scope, so updating that would not update the $rootScope value, so overall the whole code should be uniform for the scope and the rootScope to be correctly updated, and that have to be done by you.

Try this link for understanding scopes https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

NOTE :: Your code is accessible on the internet, so use gulp or grunt etc for maintaining production version code (concat,uglify etc).